# remove characters from web link then download

Tags: python, excel, urllib, xlsx

I currently have about 1000 web links to excel files that I want to download. There is no pattern in the name of the docs so I have just scraped all of the web links, some of them are shown below.

```
VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx
VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx
VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx
VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx
VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx
VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx
VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx
```

One of the main problems is that each of these links has `VM300:1` at the start of it, which is not part of the link. How can I go about remvoing this 'VM300:1' from the start of every link, there is about 1000links so doing it manually is not viable.

Once that error is fixed, my code to download the files still does not work?

this is my current code:

```
import urllib2

urlfiles = ['https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx',
            'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx',
            'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx']


urllib2.urlopen(urlfiles)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the closing quotation mark for the 3rd URL in your second block of code.

Comment: No, that's not a fix

Comment: Are you using Python 2 for a reason?

Comment: Not really, no preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard python and no mention of `requests`?

```
from pathlib import Path

import requests

urls = [
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx"
]
for url in urls:
    link = url.split()[1]
    r = requests.get(link)
    with open(Path(link).name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the urls based on the space  like so:

```
>>> urls = [
"VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx",
"VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx",
"VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx",
"VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx",
"VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx",
"VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx",
"VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx"
]
>>>
>>> urlfiles = [url.split()[1] for url in urls ]
>>> print(urlfiles)
['https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx',
 'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx', 
'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx', 
'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx', 
'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx', 
'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx', 
'https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx']
```

Besides that, you need to iterate over each url in `urlfiles` to be able to open it like so:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>>
>>> for url in urlfiles:
...     urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your links literally all have `'VM300:1 '` at the start, that needs to be removed, you may as well just ignore the first 8 characters and not even bother with regex.

As for downloading all those files, assuming there are no restrictions based on cookies, sessions, etc. and using Python 3:

```
import urllib.request
from pathlib import Path

urls = [
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172775/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190130.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0004/172732/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190129.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0010/172675/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190128.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0009/172674/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190127.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0008/172673/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190126.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0007/172672/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190125.xlsx",
    "VM300:1 https://www.powerwater.com.au__data/assets/excel_doc/0011/172595/Market_Information_System_Control_daily_trading_day_190124.xlsx"
]

for url in urls:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=url[8:], filename=Path(url).name)
```